# How to resize VLC video window size when called from command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to play a video in VLC using command line, but I don't want it to play in full size. I trying to pass `width` and `height` as instructed at http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Advanced_Use_of_VLC#Video_options but it does not change the appearance of the video -- it is still played in its original resolution. What am I doing incorrectly?

Here's the command I'm using:

`/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --playlist-autostart --video-on-top --width=400 --height=400 ./2013-london-snow.mov`

As I understand their online documentation is outdated. Maybe someone could point to the source code of command line interface.

Comment: Have you tried `man vlc`? Or `vlc --longhelp --advanced`?

Comment: Thanks, looked up but none of the mentioned ones (--width, --height, --scale) appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--no-embedded-video --no-autoscale`.

Comment: This does make a small video window but it leaves a giant empty VLC container window behind it

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this too, but in VLC version 3, I couldn't get it to work.

The new beta version 4 (nightly builds) can process the --width parameter and resize the vid.
I did notice that it **only** responded to the --width=xxx parameter and calculate the height according to its ratio.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1117222)